# How to get Records from multiple tables using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, join

I have 5 tables Workflow as 'A',WorkflowSteps as 'B',AppUser as 'C' ,AppRoles as 'D' and AppDepartment as 'E' I want to get the record in the way that the

1) matching records from A and B based on workflowId

2) matching Records From B and C, B and D, B and E because table B have foreign keys UserId, RoleId and DepartmentId

but the problem is for some column in B UserId is null some have DepartmentId as Null and some have RoleId is Null so inner join won't work

here is my query it will have to fetch three rows but i am getting 0

```
var workflows = (from q in _context.WorkFlowSteps
                         join p in _context.WorkFlow
                         on q.WorkFlowId equals p.WorkFlowId
                         join r in _context.AppUsers
                         on q.ApprovalUserId equals r.UserId
                         from dep in _context.AppDepartment
                         from role in _context.AppRoles
                         where (q.DepartmentId == dep.DepartmentId) &&
                               (q.RoleId == role.RoleId)&& 
                               (q.WorkFlowId == id && 
                                q.IsAllowed == true && 
                                p.WebSiteId == WebsiteId)
                         select new WorkFlowViewModel
                         {
                             UserId =Convert.ToInt32(q.ApprovalUserId.HasValue?
                                      q.ApprovalUserId:
                                      (q.DepartmentId.HasValue? 
                                       q.DepartmentId:
                                       q.RoleId)),
                             ModeId = p.ModeId,
                             WebSiteId = p.WebSiteId,
                             Step = q.StepNo,
                             Name =q.ApprovalUserId.HasValue ? 
                                   p.Name :
                                   (q.DepartmentId.HasValue? 
                                    dep.Name :
                                    r.Name),
                             WorkFlowId = p.WorkFlowId
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: `but the problem is for some column in B UserId is null some have DepartmentId as Null and some have RoleId is Null so inner join won't work` do `left join` for this

Comment: As @HemidAbbasov's suggestion. You can use left join for this. Visit this page to refer more: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/linq-left-join-example-in-c.html.

Comment: You should _very_ rarely join in LINQ to EF.  Instead just follow the Navigation Properties.  Your EF model knows how to join the tables for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming classes (minimum) for WorkFlowViewModel, WorkFlow, WorkFlowSteps, AppUsers, AppDepartment, AppRoles like so (implied from based off your Linq query):

```
public class WorkFlow
{
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<WorkFlowSteps> WorkFlowSteps { get; set; }
    public int WebSiteId { get; set; }
    public int ModeId { get; set; }
}
public class WorkFlowSteps
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StepNo { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
    public int WorkFlowId { get; set; }
    public WorkFlow WorkFlow { get; set; }
    public int? AppUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual AppDepartment AppDepartment { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole AppRole { get; set; }
}
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlowSteps> WorkFlowSteps { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AppDepartment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlowSteps> WorkFlowSteps { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AppRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlowSteps> WorkFlowSteps { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class WorkFlowViewModel
{
    public int WorkFlowId { get; set; }
    public int Step { get; set; }
    public int ModeId { get; set; }
    public int WebSiteId { get; set; }
    public int ApproverId { get; set; }
    public string ApproverName { get; set; }
}
```

Then this code should select and then map your data.  First step uses EF and navigation paths to Select your data.  Second step creates your desired output or "decorated object".

```
// Inputs consist of workflow id & website id & EF context
var selectedRecords = _context.WorkFlows
    .Include("WorkFlowSteps")
    .Include("WorkFlowSteps.AppUser")
    .Include("WorkFlowSteps.AppDepartment")
    .Include("WorkFlowSteps.AppRole")
    .Select(r => r.Id == id && r.WebSiteId == websiteId && r.WorkFlowSteps.IsAllowed);

var myModel = (from q in selectedRecords
               select new WorkFlowViewModel
               {
                   ApproverId = Convert.ToInt32(q.WorkFlowStep.AppUserId.HasValue 
                        ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppUserId 
                        : (q.WorkFlowStep.AppDepartmentId.HasValue 
                            ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppDepartmentId 
                            : (q.WorkFlowStep.AppRoleId.HasValue ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppRoleId, "0"))),
                   ModeId = q.ModeId,
                   WebSiteId = q.WebSiteId,
                   Step = q.WorkFlowStep.StepNo,
                   ApproverName = q.WorkFlowStep.AppUserId.HasValue 
                        ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppUser.Name 
                        : (q.WorkFlowStep.AppDepartmentId.HasValue
                            ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppDepartment.Name 
                            : (q.WorkFlowStep.AppRoleId.HasValue ? q.WorkFlowStep.AppRole.Name, "")),
                   WorkFlowId = q.WorkFlowId
               }).ToList();
```